# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my code, I'm encountering an error with "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'." I've attempted to modify the code, but I'm still encountering the same error. Please assist me in resolving this issue.

@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
ticket_id = int(request.data['ticket_id'])

```
    try:
        tick_page = TicketPage.objects.get(ticket_id=ticket_id, status='open')
        tick_page.status = 'Closed'
        tick_page.Updated_timestamp = datetime.now()
        tick_page.save()
        return JsonResponse('Ticket Handled Successfully', status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED, safe=False)
    except TicketPage.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse('TicketID is Invalid or does not exists', status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, safe=False)
```